# Can we deploy Xamarin.iOS app into simulator using windows Machine without connecting to Mac agent

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Any one suggest me using visual studio can we deploy any of the iOS application in Simulator not connecting to Mac Agent??? Through Windows Machine.

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

No it is an apple licensing requirement.  There is the xamarin live player in preview which will let you test apps on an iphone without an mac

https://www.xamarin.com/live

Answer (score 1):

Simulator for iOS always runs on Mac, there is no simulator for iOS for Windows. You can only cast the screen to Windows so that you don't have to look on the Mac screen, but that's all, you need a mac for that (and this requires Visual Studio Enterprise which you probably don't have - assuming from your other statements).

If you want to develop without Mac you can try to install Xamarin Live Player on your iOS device. And also you can't build the final package without a Mac (and it also required for uploading it to the store), just in this case you can possibly get some Mac in the cloud and pay per hour.

If you don't have even the iOS device then you need to buy it as this can't be resolved in any way.